# h2 - How to dump selective rows by WHERE class, SCRIPT dumps the entire database

Tags: sql, import, export, h2, dump

I need to be able to EXPORT specific rows from selective tables for subsequent IMPORT on another machine. Is there a way to do that via H2's SQL grammar (like "SCRIPT FROM table WHERE column = value") OR do I need to write custom code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

H2 supports the SCRIPT command to export a SQL script, and it supports CSVWRITE to export a CSV file.

The [SCRIPT command](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) does support a table name, but not a condition. What you could do is create a temporary table, and export it.

Or you could use [CSVWRITE](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvwrite) to export a CSV file.

Or, of course, you could create your own [user defined function](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions).